# What does "on the trot" mean in tennis?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sports

Watching the pre-game broadcast for the Djokovic/Medvedev 2023 US Open men's singles championship match, I heard analyst Brad Gilbert say that Coco Gauff had won 12 in a row "on the trot" and that Djokovic would match that if he beat Medvedev.

What does "on the trot" mean?

Comment: (Sports) moderator note: moving this to English SE as there's nothing specifically tennis or sports related about this one; I'm guessing it may be British English?

Comment: 'On the trot' means consecutively. So Grauff had won 12 titles in a row, with no losses to interrupt the winning streak.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***On the trot*** is an informal expression which in your context means “one after  another”:

BRITISH informal

> in succession.
>
> - "they lost seven matches on the trot"

(Oxford Dictionaries)

[Origin:](https://idiomorigins.org/origin/on-the-trot#:%7E:text=Origin%20of%3A%20On%20the%20trot&text=This%20expression%20from%20trot%20as,from%20the%20mid%2D20th%20century.)

> This expression from trot as in running can mean either 'on the go' which dates from the late 19th century or 'in quick succession' which dates from the mid-20th century.

(Idiomsorigin.com)

Comment: This is already implicit in this answer, and mentioned in the comments, but it might be worth editing in that there is nothing specific to tennis in the expression, since that was part of the original question.